# OpenCV: My camera opens but it won't return any frames

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with OpenCV to record some videos. I have this very simple test code that records a 20 seconds video:

```
import cv2
import os
import time

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Set the video camera:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
# Here, we are letting it warm-up:
time.sleep(2.0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open webcam") # This returns True

# Setting the codec to jpg image sequences:
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
frameSize = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fps = 12.5
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')

out = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join(base_dir, 'videos', f'test_video.avi'), fourcc, fps, frameSize)


print("Recording...")
t_end = time.time() + 20
while time.time() < t_end:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(ret) # This returns False
    print(frame) #... and None
    if ret:
        out.write(frame)     
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Done!)
```

The problem is that my camera is opening, but it doesn't read the frame correctly as ret, frame returns False and None respectively.

Any ideas on what may be causing this, and/or how to solve it?

Comment: Comment out cap.set and set this cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: the sleep(2) is pointless and can even be harmful. -- isOpened may be true initially, but then you try to change the device's parameters. _after_ that you should again check for isOpened